# Can Auth0 be used for Craft Commerce user accounts?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, permissions, password, authentication

I want to use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to provide a Single Sign On (SSO) for a couple of services I am integrating, one of which is Craft Commerce user accounts. Does Craft Commerce allow something like Auth0 for authentication?

Comment: Hey @bobartlett . Did you create a plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

Craft Commerce and Craft does not support that service out of the box. A Craft plugin would need to created using their PHP Package: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-PHP